# Woocommerce not include child category product BUT allow filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WC 3.6 (native filtering attributes)
In category page I want to hide child cagetories' products.
I used this code from
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275213/remove-child-products-from-woocommerce-category-page/275260

```
function exclude_product_cat_children( $wp_query ) {
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
    $wp_query->set( 
        'tax_query', array( array (
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
            'include_children' => false
        ) )
    );
}
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

**PROBLEM:**
But it erases [ line 3: **$wp_query->set** ] the filtering query for attributes from the main query (if exists)

So if I use that code the category page:

A) https://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/product-category/spiti-kipos/atmokatharistes-tzamokatharistes/

will not show child's category products but the page:

B) https://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/product-category/spiti-kipos/atmokatharistes-tzamokatharistes/?filter_xoritikotita=0-18lt&query_type_xoritikotita=or

will not filter the products by xoritikotita attribute ( 0-18lt)

A) + B) will show the same products if exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) is used.

**HELP:**
Is it possible to keep the attributes query and not include child category's products ?